# Understand JQuery Selector expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to read some JavaScript that is selecting element(s) using this expression

```
$("body > div:not(.layout-ignore):not(.ui-loader)")
```

I get that its starting at the body but is that the Greater Than (>) symbol saying select all div elements within the body element that do not have .layout-ignore and also not .ui-loader class attributes?

Can anyone explain to me this syntax? Also point me to some online documentation that helps me further understand this selector expression.

Cheers

Comment: it can be written as `$("body > div:not(.layout-ignore.ui-loader)") `

Comment: It may be easier to write it as `$('body').children('div').not('.layout-ignore, .ui-loader')`.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery uses CSS selectors as its basis. The MDN has an extremely thorough guide as to what these are and how they work.

Please see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

and here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started

In your example it means any div (that is not of class .layout-ignore or .ui-loader) that is a child of body. Meaning nested divs would not be selected.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

> ...is that the Greater Than (>) symbol saying select all div elements within the body element that do not have .layout-ignore and also not .ui-loader class attributes?

The `>` is saying that the `div` that matches must be an immediate child of `body`. It's called a "[child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators)". So the only `div` elements that can possibly match are immediate children of `body`, they can't be inside another intermediate element. So:

```
<body>
    <div><!-- This div matches the selector -->
        <div><!-- But this div does not --></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The two `:not` qualifiers (which are the "[negation pseudoclass](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation)") are saying that the `div` cannot have the class `layout-ignore` and cannot have the class `ui-loader`.

So in total:

```
<body>
    <div><!-- This div matches the selector --></div>
        <div><!-- But this div does not, it's not a direct child of body --></div>
    </div>
    <div class="layout-ignore"><!-- This does not because it has layout-ignore --></div>
    <div class="ui-loader"><!-- And neither does this, because it has ui-loader --></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `body > div` code is select all div that are direct children of body (http://devdocs.io/css/child_selectors)

```
<body>
    <div>first</div>
    <span>
        <div>second</div>
    </span>
</body>
```

(ignore that the html markup isn't valid here) but with that selector it will only select the div with the text first.

the :not selector will exclude everything within it: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

```
<body>
    <div>first</div>
    <span>
        <div>second</div>
    </span>
    <div class="example"></div>
</body>
```

`body>div:not(.example)` with the `body>div` it will select both the "first" div and the .example but will exclude `.example` div from the collection.